# A chart element could not be found in the series collection

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm attempting to create a chart element and keep getting an error:

> A chart element with the name 'test1' could not be found in the 'SeriesCollection'.

for the corresponding code:

```
    'Create chart series
    Dim AnnualSeries As New Series
    AnnualSeries.Name = "test1"
    AnnualSeries.Points.DataBindXY(MonthArray, GraphVectorY)
    AnnualChart.Series("test1")("DrawingStyle") = "Emboss"
```

This is run in a script inside the aspx page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the Series to the Chart.

```
AnnualChart.Series.Add(AnnualSeries)
```

My VB might be a bit rusty, but hopefully you get the idea.